# Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token { in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I receive this bug when using method POST. Please help me.

```
  angular_min.js:114 SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 71
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at wc (angular_min.js:16)
    at cc (angular_min.js:88)
    at angular_min.js:89
    at n (angular_min.js:7)
    at hd (angular_min.js:89)
    at c (angular_min.js:91)
    at angular_min.js:126
    at m.$eval (angular_min.js:141)
    at m.$digest (angular_min.js:138)
```

My code:
var json=
             {parameter_name:"amount","parameter_value":$scope.it.amount};

```
         var arr=[];
         arr.push(json);
         $scope.object={formula:$scope.it.formula_saving_point};
         $scope.companyTemp={company_id:com_id};
         var url = API_URL + "cumulative_point_formula";    
         var cmd = "check_formula";
         var jsonFinal = JSON.stringify({json_parameter: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)),
          company: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.companyTemp)),
          cumulative_point_formula: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.object))});
```

This log **jsonFinal**

```
{"json_parameter":[{"parameter_name":"amount","parameter_value":"111111111"}],"company":{"company_id":40743},"cumulative_point_formula":{"formula":"amount/10000"}}
```

This is method POST:

```
 $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: $.param({cm: cmd, dt: jsonFinal}),
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (response) {
              console.log("success");
});
```

How to fix this bug?

Comment: did you duplicate your code in this question on purpose?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.companyTemp))` Um... why?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Old-school way of deep cloning objects. In a lot of browsers it is surprisingly still the fastest way to do it

Comment: @Claies I'm sorry. I can't fix it, I hope somebody help me.

Comment: @slebetman Can you solve my problem? Please help me!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 this is a way I studied in ebook? It's wrong?

Comment: @john What's the point of serializing your object when you immediately deserialize it afterwards?

Comment: @slebetman Since John is using Angular, he should really use the different cloning utility functions offered by Angular.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks. I change it to   var jsonFinal = JSON.stringify({
      json_parameter: arr,
      company: $scope.companyTemp,
      cumulative_point_formula: $scope.object
  }); but i still produces an error. Can give me  suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look to your error it originated from **JSON.parse** and not **$http**. I believe this error is being caused by this line

```
var jsonFinal = JSON.stringify({json_parameter: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)),
    company: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.companyTemp)),
    cumulative_point_formula: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.object))});
```

where this chunk of code here is pretty redundant:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.companyTemp))
```

**stringify** > **parse** would result the same as **$scope.companyTemp** and so are the others and as the same as this:

```
  var jsonFinal = JSON.stringify({
      json_parameter: arr,
      company: $scope.companyTemp,
      cumulative_point_formula: $scope.object
  });
```

**JSON.parse** converts JSON string to a valid JavaScript object

**JSON.stringify** converts JavaScript object to string

If it still produces an error I believe one of these three **arr**, **$scope.companyTemp**, **$scope.object** has an invalid value.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Preenz, I got it and I try your way but I unsolve it. I receive "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 71" again. But I console.log the jsonFinal and test it in POSTMAN. It's run. The result is :[
  {
    "result": "1"
  }
]
Can help me again?

Comment: I can't totally guess what's inside these variables but make sure to check this out that these have object or array values, if one of these is a **string**, **JSON.stringify** will blow up. Check out these variables **arr**, **$scope.companyTemp**, **$scope.object**, **$scope.it.formula_saving_point**, **com_id**